# Fedora 36 Static IP disappear on network interface

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, static-ip, networkmanager

I have the following schema on Fedora 36:

installed on a virtual machine, 2 lan cards - one is to the physical network, the other is a virtual one created in vmware. e.g. ens192 - external network and ens224 - internal network.
I use ens224 LAN card as a router, it has a static address set. I have nmtui installed and I am making the changes with it.
I have installed dhcp, dns, all firewall rules.
The other virtual machines successfully get an address and have access to the Internet (the ones that are connected to ens224 network).
The problem is that for some reason the activation of the ens224 connection times out and fails, after which the static address disappears and the NetworkManager service needs to be restarted. Anyone have any idea what exactly is going on?

```
Nov 19 12:17:44 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <info>  [1668853064.1786] device (ens224): Activation: starting connection 'ens224' (4f6b053f-2e63-38a7-9875-98a3721ba386)
Nov 19 12:17:44 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <info>  [1668853064.1791] device (ens224): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 12:17:44 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <info>  [1668853064.1815] device (ens224): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 12:17:44 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <info>  [1668853064.2097] device (ens224): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 12:17:44 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <info>  [1668853064.2122] dhcp4 (ens224): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 19 12:18:29 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <info>  [1668853109.1471] device (ens224): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 12:18:29 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <warn>  [1668853109.1485] device (ens224): Activation: failed for connection 'ens224'
Nov 19 12:18:29 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <info>  [1668853109.1491] device (ens224): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 19 12:18:29 okd.local NetworkManager[1972]: <info>  [1668853109.1579] dhcp4 (ens224): canceled DHCP transaction

[root@okd zones]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:74:90:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0
    inet 172.16.1.86/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft 477sec preferred_lft 477sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe74:90a4/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:74:90:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp19s0
[root@okd zones]#
```

Comment: Is the static IP address of ens224 also configured through NetworkManager? Does nmcli show the correct profile being applied to it? (Does `nmcli con show` confirm that the profile has IP config mode set to static/manual and not DHCP?)

Comment: You pointed me to the right answer. When I added the configuration via nmcli, things happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1686 directed me where to look for the problem.

```
nmcli con mod ens33 ipv4.method manual
```

I thought that when running nmtui there would be no need to configure nmcli as well.